# jQuery show alert on dropdown menu change

Tags: jquery

I have a button and a canvas. On button press, a new box can be created. Each box placed on the canvas this way includes a form with two fields: a dropdown (`<select>`) and an integer input field. I only focus on the prior now.

Imagine that the user has pressed the "New Box" button three times, hence having created three separate boxes, each containing the above-mentioned form fields. I want to show a popup any time the user changes any of the dropdown values.

Since all boxes created have the same `indi-box` class name, and the select tag has a `name` attribute of `chosen_string`, I came up with the following jQuery snippet:

```
// check for value change in any of the forms
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".indi-box select[name='chosen_string']").on("change", function(){
        alert($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

However, no alert message pops up. I also tried a slightly different syntax but also no success:

```
$(".indi-box select[name='chosen_string']").change( function() {
    alert($(this).value);
});
```

I placed the full functioning code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1a0spbwx/1/). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `true` as an argument to [jQuery's clone() method](https://api.jquery.com/clone/), so that you copy any event handlers attached to the element you are cloning.

```js
let clone = $("#box-copy").clone(true).removeAttr("hidden").removeAttr("id");
```

This would give you:

```
<button id="add-new-btn" title="Add new box">New Box</button>

<!-- COPY OF BOX (HIDDEN) -->
<div id="box-copy" class="indi-box" style="" hidden>
  <form id="test-id" method="post" action="">
    <p>
      <label for="id_chosen_string">Please select:</label>
      <select name="chosen_string" required="">
      <option value="" selected="">Select...</option>
      <option value="a0">a0</option>
      <option value="b1">b1</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </form>

  <p>
    <label for="id_chosen_number">Please select:</label>
    <input type="number" name="chosen_number" placeholder="0" required>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="canvas"></div>

<script>
  $("#add-new-btn").on("click", function(){
    let clone = $("#box-copy").clone(true).removeAttr("hidden").removeAttr("id");
    clone.find("*").removeAttr("id");
    clone.draggable().resizable();
    $('#canvas').append(clone);
  });

  $("select[name='chosen_string']").on("change", function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through your fiddle and I saw that you have hidden the parent div with html hidden attribute which eventually fails to attach event handler to the element because it does not exist. To accomplish this, you need to understand Event Delegation.

For more about [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('change','select', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pahday/umd45j9p/7/)